# C error expected identifer before '(' token in structs

Tags: c

I am trying to change my data in my cacheSets but I am getting this error for some reason. I have a cacheSet global to make things easier for me.

```
typedef struct cacheLine
{
  int valid;
  int counter;
  int tag;
  int block;

};

typedef struct cacheSet
{
  int setnum;
  int E;
  struct cacheLine *lines;
};

void createCache(int E, int S);
void hitormiss(int address,int tag, int offset);

struct cacheSet *sets;


void createCache(int E, int S)
{
  sets = malloc(sizeof(sets) * S);

  for(int i = 0; i < S; i++)
  {
     sets->lines = malloc(sizeof(sets->lines) * E);
     sets->setnum = i;
     sets->E = E;
  }
}
```

This function has all the errors, all the lines that I'm trying to access tags,offsets and counter are throwing all the errors. So everyone line that has (lines + i) is throwing an error. I might be confusing my self because I'm trying to access data in a struct that's in a struct.

```
void hitormiss(int address,int tag, int offset)
{

for(int i = 0; i < sets->E; i++)
{
    /*if tag == to the address tag then its a hit*/
    if(sets->(lines + i)->tag == tag)
    {
        printf("%d H\n",address);
        sets->(lines + i)->counter++;

    }
    /*if theres a miss*/
    else if(sets->(lines + i)->tag != tag)
    {
        printf("%d M\n",address);
        sets->(lines + i)->tag = tag;
        sets->(lines + i)->block = offset;
        sets->(lines + i)->counter = 0;
    }
    /*cold miss*/
    else
    {
        printf("%d M\n",address);
        sets->(lines + i)->tag = tag;
        sets->(lines + i)->block = offset;
        sets->(lines + i)->counter = 0;

    }

}

}
```

Comment: What is `sets->(lines + i)->tag` suppose to do? You use the `->` to fetch an attribute. You cannot do arithmetic there, you must provide a valid attribute name. Did you perhaps mean `sets[lines + i]->tag`?

Comment: I think he wants `sets->lines[i].tag`.

Comment: `(sets->lines+i)->tag` would also work, but subscript notation is easier to read.

Comment: I knew i was confusing myself, sets->lines[i].tag is right, but why isn't the -> used to get the tag? Isn't lines a pointer?

Comment: `struct->lines` is a member of the struct, but `(lines+i)` is not.

Comment: @Bobby.lock `sets->lines[i].tag`, `(*(sets->lines + i)).tag` and `(sets->lines + i)->tag` are all equivalent. (`sets->lines` and `(sets->lines + i)` are `struct cacheLine *`. `*(sets->lines + i)` and `sets->lines[i]` are `struct cacheLine`.)